# GPIO.output(7,0) RuntimeError: The GPIO channel has not been set up as an OUTPUT

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

This is my code. I tried running it on terminal however, it gave me an      error. The error was RuntimeError: The GPIO channel has not been set up as an OUTPUT

```
# CamJam EduKit 3 - Robotics
# Worksheet 3 - Motor Test Code
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO # Import the GPIO Library
import time # Import the Time library

# Set the GPIO modes
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

# Set the GPIO Pin mode
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.OUT)

# Turn all motors off
GPIO.output(7, 0)
GPIO.output(8, 0)
GPIO.output(9, 0)
GPIO.output(10, 0)

# Turn the right motor forwards
GPIO.output(9, 0)
GPIO.output(10, 1)

# Turn the left motor forwards
GPIO.output(7, 0)
GPIO.output(8, 1)

# Wait for 1 second
time.sleep(1)

# Reset the GPIO pins (turns off motors too)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: What did the error say?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: GPIO.output(7,0)     RuntimeError: The GPIO channel has not been set up as an OUTPUT.

Comment: Have you tried power cycling your Pi? If you were using it before, and forgot to cleanup, then it's still in use and you need to power cycle.

Comment: No i dont think I have thank you. Would it be a problem if the pins where set up incorrectly aswell?